# One liner terminal command for renaming all files in directory to their hash values

Tags: linux, bash, terminal

I am new to bash loops and trying to rename all files in a directory to their appropriate md5 values.

There are 5 sample files in the directory.
For testing purpose, I am trying to first just print md5 hashes of all files in the directory using below command and it is working fine.

```
for i in `ls`; do md5sum $i; done
```

Output:

```
edc47be8af3a7d4d55402ebae9f04f0a  file1
72cf1321d5f3d2e9e1be8abd971f42f5  file2
4b7b590d6d522f6da7e3a9d12d622a07  file3
357af1e7f8141581361ac5d39efa4d89  file4
1445c4c1fb27abd9061ada3b30a18b44  file5
```

Now I am trying to rename each file with its appropriate md5 hashes by following command:

```
for i in `ls`; do mv $i md5sum $i; done
```

Failed Output:

```
mv: target 'file1' is not a directory
mv: target 'file2' is not a directory
mv: target 'file3' is not a directory
mv: target 'file4' is not a directory
mv: target 'file5' is not a directory
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: why call ls when what you want is `for i in *` ?

Comment: @stark - Thanks for the comment. Both are working fine. The actual issue was at another place. I have posted the answer.

Answer (score -1):

Syntax. Yes I was giving wrong syntax.

With some trial and errors with the command, I finally came up with the correct syntax.

I noticed that `md5sum $i` was giving me 2 column-ed output.

```
edc47be8af3a7d4d55402ebae9f04f0a  file1
72cf1321d5f3d2e9e1be8abd971f42f5  file2
4b7b590d6d522f6da7e3a9d12d622a07  file3
357af1e7f8141581361ac5d39efa4d89  file4
1445c4c1fb27abd9061ada3b30a18b44  file5
```

By firing second command `for i in ls; do mv $i md5sum $i; done`, I was basically telling terminal to do something like :

```
mv $i md5sum $i
```

which, upto my knowledge, turns out to be

```
mv file1 <md5 value> file1  <-- this was the issue.
```

How I resolved the issue?

I used `cut` command to filter out required value and made new one-liner as below:

```
for i in `ls`; do mv $i "$(md5sum $i | cut -d " " -f 1)"; done
```

[Edit]
According to another answer and comment by @stark, @choroba and @tripleee, it is better to use * instead of ls.

> for i in *; do mv $i "$(md5sum $i | cut -d " " -f 1)"; done

@choroba's answer is also a good addition here. Turning it into one-liner requirement, below is his solution:

> for i in *; do m=$(md5sum $i); mv "$i" ${m%% *};done

Comment: Still [don't use `ls` in scripts.](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)  And [quote your variables.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10067266/when-to-wrap-quotes-around-a-shell-variable)

Answer (score -1):

Your command is expanded to

```
mv file1 edc47be8af3a7d4d55402ebae9f04f0a file1
```

When `mv` has more than two non-option arguments, it understands the last argument to be the target directory to which all the preceding files should be moved. But there's no directory `file1`.

You can use parameter expansion to remove the filename from the string.
Parameter expansion is usually faster then running an external command like `cut` or `sed`, but if you aren't renaming thousands of files, it probably doesn't matter.

```
for f in *; do
    m=$(md5sum "$f")
    mv "$f" ${m%% *}  # Remove everything after the first space
done
```

Also note that I don't parse the output of `ls`, but let the shell expand the glob. It's safer and works (with proper quoting) for filenames containing whitespace.

Comment: You get it exactly right. I realised the mistake while doing some trial-and-errors. 
Secondly, I am looking for one-liner which can be directly fired from terminal. I tried your command `for i in *; do m=$(md5sum $i) mv "$i" ${m%% *};done` and somehow it's giving me error.

Comment: You miss a semicolon before `mv`

Comment: While doing some trials, I also came across approach similar to yours but gave me error.
reference : https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/102651/232683

Comment: I added semicolon and it's working perfectly fine. Awesome! 
I thought semi should only be used while whole command is complete in the `done` part.

Comment: No, you need to use newlines or semicolons to separate commands.

Comment: Got to learn a new thing today. Thank you.